# Setting content into multiple TinyMCE textarea?

Tags: php, jquery, tinymce

I have 3 tinymce textarea, in my page. And I want to populate these text areas from ajax.

I know the name of the original `textarea` field, but

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(value);
```

does not work, since I dont have any active editor.

Here is a basic example of my code

```
.
.
.
function(data) {
$.each(data, function(key,value)) {
    $("#"+key).val(value); //"#"+key is the id of tinymce editors in my form
},
"json"
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: im not sure but look at DOM using `console.log(tinyMCE.activeEditor);` should give you an array of objects. its just a feeling not sure though :) so you could be looking at something like this instead `tinyMCE.activeEditor[0].setContent(value);` `console.log()` is use for firebug to debug for firefox

Comment: oops sorry my bad ... its `tinyMCE.editors[0].iframeHTML = value`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
for(i=0; i < tinymce.editors.length; i++){
    tinymce.editors[i].setContent(value);
}
```

Edit: You may also use the following

```
for(i=0; i < tinymce.editors.length; i++){
    tinymce.get(tinymce.editors[i].id).setContent(value);
}
```

Comment: But I need to setup the content as per their id

Comment: thieve lol check for their ID using a for, or any other loop to go throw each of them and get their IDs but if you only have 3 tinys u should know which one is which, it's not like they will change their indexing position

Comment: @Val: depending on the CMS the point of initialization may differ. This may yield to different ids when the editor id gets set dynamically.

Comment: my point is that there are many ways, just giving up that easy, e.g. not exploring the DOM im agreeing with u that for loop is a good idea :) but u could be right on the indexing numbers :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the tinyMCE jquery editor you can try the following code

```
$.each(tinyMCE.editors, function(index, editor){
     editor.setContent(value);
);
```