# Saving multiple TinyMCE instances

Tags: javascript, tinymce, autosave

I have multiple instances of TinyMCE on one page.

I have a javascript autosave running in the background that automatically saves the forms in the database via a POST request. This works good with one form where I can set the element ID in the init. However, in my scenario, the user can have a variable number of TinyMCE forms, so having multiple hardcoded element ID's do not seem practical.

TL;DR: Dynamically grab all instances of TinyMCE in the same page without knowing the instance ID. Or, any other approach to save multiple forms in one auto_save() function.

Comment: After searching StackOverflow some more I found a question that is similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553716/setting-content-into-multiple-tinymce-textarea

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way Brett decribed is correct. Here is the code you may call whenever needed, i.e. in your auto_save() function:

```
for (var i = 0; i < tinymce.editors.length; i++) {
    // you need to do what is needed here
    // example: write the content back to the form foreach editor instance
    tinymce.editors[i].save();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could iterate through the [tinyMCE.editors](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/API3%3aproperty.tinymce.editors) collection in your auto_save() function.

Comment: +1 that is the way to go, i will post the relevant code in an own answer